# TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I was trying to create a basic python calculator

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Calculator:
    def __int__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def add(self):
        return self.x + self.y
    def sub(self):
        return self.x - self.y
    def multi(self):
        return self.x * self.y
    def div(self):
        return self.x / self.y

    def convert(self,a,b):
        try:
            int_a = int(a)
            int_b = int(b)
        except ValueError:
            int_a = float(a)
            int_b = float(b)
        return int_a,int_b

run = True

while run:
    print "Please choose what you'd like to do:"
    print "0: Addition"
    print "1: Subtraction"
    print "2: Multiplication"
    print "3: Division"
    print "4: Quit Application"

    choice = raw_input()

    if choice == "0":
        str_a = raw_input("Enter 1st number : ")
        str_b = raw_input("Enter 2nd number : ")
        c = Calculator(str_a,str_b)
        c.add()
```

but I am getting error like below:

```
  c = Calculator(str_a,str_b)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

please anyone help me to fix this issue

Comment: You misspelled `__init__`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a simple typo in the initializer name.

Comment: HI 

thanks for your help.

but wen i run this, i entered 2 numbers, on that add() i used return. But i am not getting any answers on screen.

Comment: OK, so what part of that code are you expecting to print the answer on screen?

Comment: You have to print output. After that, it can be appeared. print c.add()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I am expecting what you need,

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

    class Calculator:
        def __init__(self,x,y):
            self.x = int(x)
            self.y = int(y)
        def add(self):
            return self.x + self.y
        def sub(self):
            return self.x - self.y
        def multi(self):
            return self.x * self.y
        def div(self):
            return self.x / self.y

        def convert(self,a,b):
            try:
                int_a = int(a)
                int_b = int(b)
            except ValueError:
                int_a = float(a)
                int_b = float(b)
            return int_a,int_b

    run = True

    while run:
        print "Please choose what you'd like to do:"
        print "0: Addition"
        print "1: Subtraction"
        print "2: Multiplication"
        print "3: Division"
        print "4: Quit Application"

        choice = raw_input()

        if choice == "0":
            str_a = raw_input("Enter 1st number : ")
            str_b = raw_input("Enter 2nd number : ")
            c = Calculator(str_a,str_b)
            print c.add()
```

Answer (score -1):

Please use `input` instead of `raw_input`

```
   str_a = input("Enter 1st number : ")
   str_b = input("Enter 2nd number : ")
```

`raw_input` takes string by default.

Comment: -1: This is 2.x-specific, *dangerous* in 2.x, and ignores the fact that OP has already implemented something to convert explicitly (just isn't actually *using* it yet), which is preferred.